# PHP MySQL INSERT Error and i can't find it o_o

Tags: php, mysql

I will make it short: I have a problem with the INSERT Command but i'm not able to find it...

```
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO players (username, x, direction, char) 
VALUES ('test', '20', 'right', '2')");
```

The error message is:

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to 
your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'char) VALUES 
('test', '20', 'right', '2')' at line 1
```

Where is the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Char is a reserved word. Change the name of the field.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using a reserved keyword.. A list can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

Your current keyword is: `char`

escape this by using a backtick in the MySQL Language (`)

Or change the column name.

Answer (score 0):

Char is restricted keyword, replace char with hero maybe?